# C++ - zlib uncompress function crashes program

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

I should note that this program is adhering (at least, trying to) to the [Tiled API](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format).

I'm trying to use the `uncompress()` function in zlib, but for some reason my program crashes whenever I call the function. This is what I have, and all of the parameters look right, so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

```
// const char* filedata passed in function is Zlib compressed and Base64 encoded

uLong inLen = static_cast<uLong>((strlen(filedata)*6)/8);   // Calculate the length
std::string inBuffer = BASE64_DECODE(filedata);    // My data

uLongf outLen = static_cast<uLongf>(width*height*4);    // Tiled API specification
Bytef* outBuffer = new Bytef(outLen);     // Destination

int ret = uncompress(outBuffer, &outLen,
              reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(&inBuffer[0]), inLen);
```

`ret` returns nothing, the program crashes. Does anybody have any ideas? Here is the `BASE64_DECODE` function:

```
std::string BASE64_DECODE(std::string const& encoded_string)
{
    int in_len = encoded_string.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int in_ = 0;

    unsigned char char_array_4[4], char_array_3[3];
    std::string ret;

    while(in_len-- && ( encoded_string[in_] != '=') && is_base64(encoded_string[in_]))
    {
        char_array_4[i++] = encoded_string[in_]; in_++;

        if (i == 4)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <4; i++)
                char_array_4[i] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[i]);

            char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
            char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
            char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

            for (i = 0; (i < 3); i++)
                ret += char_array_3[i];

            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if(i)
    {
        for (j = i; j <4; j++)
          char_array_4[j] = 0;

        for (j = 0; j <4; j++)
          char_array_4[j] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[j]);

        char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
        char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

        for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++) ret += char_array_3[j];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**EDIT:** If you're looking at this in the future, make sure you `delete` the `outBuffer` variable later in the program to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Is `inLen` really the same as the size of `inBuffer`?

Comment: @CongXu Fixed the length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bytef` isn't used with a constructor that takes a length argument. You probably meant `Bytef* outBuffer = new Bytef[outLen];` (square brackets).

I think `Bytef` is usually typedef-ed to some primitive type anyway, so using it is analogous to something like `new int[len]` or `new uint64_t[len]`.